# What data can be obtained when someone accesses my site?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, cgi

I'm creating a function that logs data from the machine that accessed my website. I already know that it is possible in PHP to get the IP and the browser string ($ _ SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']). And from the IP, I identify the user's city / state / country.
What I need to know is what other data can be obtained in PHP (or another language) when someone accesses a page from my website.

Comment: Only what they send you - and none of it's reliable; they could use a proxy to mask their IP and spoof any HTTP header.

Comment: FYI: IP, user agent, none of it is reliable as it is the user's discretion to pass the information and there are ways to modify it. Also, geocoding (turning an IP into a physical location) is not an exact science and is subject to varying levels of confidence based on the IP/locale.

Comment: Okay. I already know about the proxy and VPNs. What I need to know is only if there are other data besides the IP and User Agent that can be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have already discovered other information that can be obtained from the machine that accessed the website. It's the complete URL. What helps a lot, because if you are trying to break into the server with MySQL injection or PHP injection, we have how to know exactly the method they are using and provide protection.

$url_completa = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";